# My first is coming today!

Tags: riddle

> I will be one, but I'm not yet,
>
> I'm somewhat like, but not a pet,
>
> My needs are few, but frequent,
>
> I'm still quite new, what an event!

What am I?

Hint (Sort of):

> And what might my name be?

Comment: Gratz on your first one! :)

Comment: Is the name (rot13) "Oerag we"?

Comment: @BruceWayne It nearly was.  But we went with Conan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a

> Baby

I will be one, but I'm not yet,

> You'll be a person when you're born but you're not born yet

I'm somewhat like, but not a pet,

> A baby needs to be cared for like a pet but isn't a pet

My needs are few, but frequent,

> A baby needs to be fed and nappy changed but not much else

I'm still quite new, what an event!

> Childbirth is a big, sometimes long event but with a celebration at the end

Comment: You got it, +1 but the 'one' in the first hint was ...numerical.